# How to Deploy angular js frontend (static files) module as separate service in GCP App Engine in flexible environment

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to Deploy angular js frontend (static files) as separate services in Google cloud App Engine in flexible environment .

I have deployed backend as separate services by configuring app.yaml.

Can anyone explain detailed procedure about how to deploy angular js in frontend as separate service in Google Cloud Platform App Engine Flexible environment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Deploy angular js frontend (static files) as separate service in Google cloud app engine in flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659434/how-to-deploy-angular-js-frontend-static-files-as-separate-service-in-google-c)

Comment: Here is a [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)  you can follow to host Angular app in App Engine

Comment: i am using spring boot as backend with angular js frontend app . Above code provide detailed steps for node js with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your Spring Boot backend service and host Frontend on Cloud Storage or an another App Engine service.

Cloud Storage provides static hosting capabilities. You can upload your frontend files to a Cloud Storage bucket and configure your domain to serve content from that bucket. [Here is a tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) for setting a bucket up for static hosting.

Once your backend REST endpoints are set up, the frontend app can easily communicate with them using Angular's AJAX capabilities.

Or you can create an another service and sync the data from Cloud Storage to the service. You can follow the next [tutorial](https://medium.com/@karthiksagar/how-to-deploy-angular-8-app-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp-cdd79e5cc5cf) to achieve that.

Comment: can you please outline the steps to host angular frontend on different services in google app engine ?